# Getting third monitor to work over HDMI - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display, intel

I've been searching around for a couple days but it seems that this can be a case-by-case kind of thing.

I currently have a dual monitor setup on Ubuntu 14.04. My external monitor, an ASUS HD monitor, is successfully displaying over DVI. I want to add a third monitor (second external monitor) of the same type; I have an HDMI cable and port open, so I thought I'd use that. (My laptop is a lenovo W541).

Ubuntu doesn't seem to detect the third monitor; it thinks that HDMI port is not connected to anything.

Here are my "VGA compatible controllers" from lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)
```

I'm reading at a lot of places I might need to edit xorg.conf, but I'm not sure how. Running find says xorg.conf doesn't exist, which I've read might be okay.

I'm cagey of changing drivers since I've ignorantly messed up machines pretty badly before, but if that's the solution I'll gladly do it. I currently use the open source Nouveau driver. Both "proprietary" and "proprietary, tested" versions of the Nvidia driver are available. UPDATE: I tried both the proprietary and proprietary tested drivers, and they did not resolve the problem.

Let me know if I can provide any other information.

Thanks in advance for the help, everyone! :)

Comment: try the tested drivers, the tested tag means that they will certainly work and proprietary means that they come from nvidia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question in the hopes that future web-searchers can find a solution sooner than I.

Anyways: I was unable to get the HDMI output to work with my third monitor. However, connecting the same monitor to my laptop over VGA rather than HDMI worked instantly. Ubuntu autodetected the monitor immediately.

I hope this helps someone in the future.